# Default function parameters for specific types

Tags: typescript

I have a component that renders generic items, and provide default render functions for types that extend a certain base type. However, it should be possible to use this component with an arbitrary type, if all necessary render functions are provided.

```
type BasicItem = { name: string }

const defaultName = <T extends BasicItem>(t: T) => t.name

type GetterProps<T extends unknown> = {
  getName: (t: T) => string
}

type Props<T extends unknown> = {
  items: T[]
} & (T extends BasicItem ? Partial<GetterProps<T>> : GetterProps<T>)

// error: Type '<T extends BasicItem>(t: T) => string' is not assignable to type '(t: unknown) => string'
function List<T extends unknown>({ getName = defaultName, items }: Props<T>) {
  return items.map(item => getName(item))
}

List({ items: ['a', 'b', 'c'], getName: (t) => t })

List({ items: [{ name: 'a' }, { name: 'b' }, { name: 'c' }] })
```

As seen in the code above, it doesn't work as TypeScript doesn't believe that the default value is only used for matching types. If I remove the default value, everything compiles as expected except I obviously get an error when running the code.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Is it okay for you to change `T`'s constraint to `T extends BasicItem`?

Comment: No because then I can't use strings or other types as items, if I want the name to be a computed property. If I settled with BasicItem I wouldn't need generics at all.

Comment: Perhaps not the most elegant solution but a nevertheless straightforward approach would be to use and overloaded function signature.

Comment: The easiest way to express this would be to use overloads like [this](https://tsplay.dev/we8yYW). By the way, `T extends unknown` is redundant.